# Need help removing ORA-00911 error while using oci_execute()

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g, illegal-characters, ora-00911

I am using following code to generate the SQL.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO SUBSTATION VALUES (".
            "SEQ_SUBSTATION_FEATURE_ID.NEXTVAL, ".
            "'".$_REQUEST['substationName']."', ".  // SUBSTATION NAME
            "null, ".                               // SLD_PATH       
            "null, ".                               // GEOMETRY
            "'".$_REQUEST['substationType']."', ".  // SUBSTATION_TYPE
            $_REQUEST['capacity'].", ".             // CAPACITY
            "'".$_REQUEST['address_1']."', ".       // ADDRESS_1
            "'".$_REQUEST['address_2']."', ".       // ADDRESS_2
            "'".$_REQUEST['landmark']."', ".        // LANDMARK
            "'".$_REQUEST['state']."', ".           // STATE
            "'".$_REQUEST['district']."', ".        // DISTRICT
            "'".$_REQUEST['pin']."', ".             // PIN
            $_REQUEST['noOfTransformers'].", ".     // NO_OF_TRANSFORMERS
            $_REQUEST['noOfLTBreakers'].", ".       // NO_OF_LT_BREAKERS
            $_REQUEST['noOfHTBreakers'].", ".       // NO_OF_HT_BREAKERS
            $_REQUEST['noOfHTIsolators'].", ".      // NO_OF_HT_ISOLATORS
            $_REQUEST['noOfLTBoards'].", ".         // NO_OF_LT_BOARDS
            "to_date('".$_REQUEST['commissioningDate']."','DD/MM/YYYY'), ". // COMMISSIONING DATE
            "'".$_REQUEST['schemeNo']."', ".        // SCHEME_NO
            "to_date('".$_REQUEST['schemeDate']."','DD/MM/YYYY'), ".        // SCHEME_DATE
            "'".$_REQUEST['comments']."', ".        // COMMENTS
            "'N', ".                                // APPROVED
            "null, ".                               // APPROVER
            "null);";                               // APPROVED_ON
```

Here is the SQL generated

```
INSERT INTO SUBSTATION VALUES 
(SEQ_SUBSTATION_FEATURE_ID.NEXTVAL, 'S/S 3 4400', NULL, NULL, 'D', 5000, 
'The Address 1', 'The Address 2', 'The Landmark', '15', '1', '234234', 
34, 65, 12, 98, 43, 
to_date('01/09/2010','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Scheme 12345', 
to_date('06/10/2010','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'This substation has following assets', 
'N', null, null);
```

Now, I run the SQL generated directly in SQL Developer, it works fine. But when I run the query using **oci_execute($sql)** in **PHP**, it does not work. While debugging using the following code:

```
$st = oci_parse($conn, $sql) or die("<br />Error parsing query. ");  
if(!oci_execute($st)){  
  $err = oci_error($st);  
  echo $err['message'];  
}
```

It show the error message:

**ORA-00911 : illegal character**

Any help please.......

Comment: Please use a query with bound parameter instead of concatenating the strings together: It will make your insert easier to understand, will work when one of your inputs contains a single quote and it will prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semi-colon at the end of the generated SQL statement and try again.

Comment: Hi codo, I tried that. but no luck. See the solution that I have posetd.  Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using **oci_bind_by_name** to prepare the statement. Please refer the this link...

[Inserting data in oracle database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119145/inserting-data-in-oracle-database-using-php)

I got rid of ORA-00911. This time, error **ORA-01461**, which is ***invalid month***, while inserting date. Following link solved the problem...

[[Resolved] ORA-01461 Error on ocibindbyname](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3644496)

Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you could resolve it using bound parameters. That'll solve about five problems at once: your initial problem, readability of code, quotes, SQL injections and not to forget speed.